Blow-up rate of derivatives for weakly, but not strongly, converging sequence
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a sufficiently smooth domain and let $(f_n) \subset C^\infty(\bar \Omega)$ be a sequence such that $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ but $f_n \not \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. A prototypical example in one dimensione would be any sequence of oscillating functions, with period going to $0$, such as $f_n  = \sin(nx)$.
The first derivative of such $f_n$ have $L^2$ norms that blow up as $n \to \infty$. Indeed, suppose that this is not the case. Pick a subsequence $f_{n_k}$. Then, since $\|f_{n_k}\|_{W^{1, 2}} \leq C$, there is a further subsequence $f_{n_{k_j}}$ such that $f_{n_{k_j}} \rightharpoonup g$ in $W^{1, 2}(\Omega)$, where it must be $g = f$. Furthermore, by compact embedding $f_{n_{k_j}} \to f$ strongly in $L^2(\Omega)$. Since the subsequence $f_{n_k}$ is arbitrary, by a well-known characterization of converging sequences this would imply that $f_n \to f$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, contradicting the hypothesis.
One can also argue by elliptic regularity that the second derivative blows-up (indeed, one cannot have a bounded second derivative and a blowing up first derivative).
If I take any example that come to my mind, it is always true that $\|\nabla^2 f_n\|_{L^2} \sim \|\nabla f_n\|^2_{L^2}$. For example, for $f_n = \sin(nx)$, one has $\|f_n'\|_{L^2} \sim n$ and $\|f''_n\|_{L^2} \sim n^2$. Is this true in general? Is it true even if we take non-smooth sequences, such as $(f_n) \subset W^{2, 2}(\Omega)$?

The statement is false, as I managed to get a counterexample. Consider
$$
f_n = \sin(nx) + \frac{1}{n^3}\cos(n^3x) \,.
$$
Clearly, $f_n \rightharpoonup 0$, $f'_n \sim n$, but $f''_n \sim n^3$.

The Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality implies
$$
\|\nabla f\|_{L^2}^2 \le C \|f\|_{L^2} \|\nabla^2 f\|_{L^2}
$$
for suitable $f$ (e.g., $f\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ or $f \in H^2(\mathbb R^N)$).
Hence, if $\|f_n\|_{L^2}$ is bounded, $\|\nabla f_n\|_{L^2} \le C n$, then
$\|\nabla^2 f_n\|_{L^2} \ge C' n^2$.

I believe there is a typo on the squared norm on the last line. Anyway, this gives a lower bound on the rate of blow up for the hessian. Do we also have an upper bound? For example, this does not exclude the possibility that $|\nabla f|{L^2} \sim n$ and $|\nabla^2 f|{L^2} \sim n^3$.
